# How to properly return a double in linux asm

Tags: c++, linux, assembly, floating-point, x86-64

When I call the function it returns 0.0000 when it should be returning 25.0000

I've tried looking for similar issues but I could find none. I have tried looking through Intel's manuals and nothing has worked so far.

I call the function through c++

```
   double t=floatingPointTest(5);
   printf("%f\n",t);
```

The asm function:

```
floatingPointTest:
        push    rbx
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp,rsp

        cvtsi2sd    xmm0,rdi
        cvtsi2sd    xmm1,rdi
        mulsd       xmm0,xmm1

        mov     rsp,rbp
        pop     rbp
        pop     rbx
        ret
```

I get 0.0000 even though rdi is 5

Comment: Stepped through it in the debugger?

Comment: Indeed, it seems that cvtss2sd xmm0,xmm0 is right after the call. Any idea why?

Comment: What is the prototype for the `floatingPointTest` in your C code?

Comment: There are two possibilities here. You have defined the prototype of `floatingPointTest` to return `float` instead of `double` and/or your first parameter to `floatingPointTest` is wrong. Your assembly code suggests your function take a a _C_ `long` (quadword in 64-bit GCC) and returns a double. The correct prototype is `extern double floatingPointTest(long val);`

Comment: It works now, I had the prototype as returning a float instead of a double. Thanks!

Comment: If an answer solved your problem consider marking this as solved by accepting the answer. The hows and whys of doing so can be found here:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/271768

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't show us a critical piece of information - what the *C++* prototype of the function `floatingPointTest` that you used was. A couple of things could cause this behaviour.

- You declared `floatingPointTest` to take a `float` or `double` as the first parameter to the function when it should have been an integer. Your assembly code uses this instruction:

  ```
  cvtsi2sd    xmm0,rdi
  ```

  We can infer that the first parameter (in *RDI*) should be a signed `long` because you use *RDI* as a source operand and because [`cvtsi2sd`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cvtsi2sd) with a 64-bit register will convert a signed quadword integer from 64-bit register to a double-precision floating-point value in the destination XMM register.
- Your prototype was declared to have a return type of `float` instead of `double`. Since your assembly code only does math as scalar doubles you need to return a `double` from the function.

A correct prototype for *C++* could be written as:

```
extern "C" double floatingPointTest(long val);
```

---

### Observations

Your code doesn't use *RBX* so there is no need to save/restore it. You don't actually need the stack frame and you can multiply a number by itself by passing the same register as source and destination to `mulsd`. This code would have done the same thing:

```
floatingPointTest:
        cvtsi2sd    xmm0, rdi
        mulsd       xmm0, xmm0
        ret
```